# asp.net with jquery error

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

i try to get an image inside dropdownlist using jquery and it's work fine with me. my code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="msdropdown/js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="msdropdown/js/jquery.dd.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="msdropdown/dd.css" />
    <!-- Script is used to call the JQuery for dropdown -->

      <script type="text/javascript"  language=”javascript” >


          $(document).ready(function (e) {
              try {
                  $("#ddlanguage").msDropDown();



              }
                catch (e) {
                    alert(e.message);
                }
          });


    </script>
```

dropdownlist:

```
<asp:DropDownList  ID="ddlanguage"  runat="server"  AutoPostBack="True"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddSelLang_SelectedIndexChanged">                   
                     <asp:ListItem  Value="en-US"  Text="English"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="ar-OM"  Text="عربي"></asp:ListItem>
 </asp:DropDownList>
```

and in C#

```
protected void BindFlag()
    {
        if (ddlanguage != null)
        {
            foreach (ListItem li in ddlanguage.Items)
            {
                li.Attributes["title"] = "Images/Flag/" + li.Value+".gif"; // setting text value of item as tooltip
            }
        }
    }
```

so everything work fine and i get image inside the list, but the problem when i try to lode some webpage use specific javascript or jquery it will give me an error message:

one page have jquery with javascript display this error :**Object doesn't support property or methode 'msDropDown'**

another page i only use javascript in it, it will close and display this message **0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: '$' is undefined**.

and there other problems: if there some action in some page, image will hided

could any one help me in that?

thanks

Comment: If you need this script global, try add this script to the layout. It will work on all pages wchich will use main layout.

Comment: Add jquery inclusion like `<script type="text/javascript" src="msdropdown/js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>` inside the `<head></head>` tags. Also based on the folder the aspx lies in, the relative path for the jquery library might also vary. In the page where you get the error use httpwatch or fiddler to find if there are any 404 errors.

Comment: @DawidJałoszyński pro i didn't understand

Comment: @Ramki thanks pro,